# CS in 64 bit mode

Tags: assembly, computer-science, x86-64

I have one simple question.

In long mode is segment register CS forced to 0 (not only CS). Then where procesor (x86-64) store actual CPL (in 32 bit mode was CPL in CS)? Official documentation don't say anything about this (or I can't find it). CPL is required for protection (paging) in long mode, isn't it?

Comment: Search for *selector* as opposed to *segment register*.

Comment: "In long mode is segment register CS forced to 0". It's wrong

Comment: I know selectors. But it doesn't solve my question. I'm allright if I think that CS is used for store CPL in long mode?

Comment: @Seraph yes (15 chars)